# Using java objects from another Maven module in GWT on the client side

Tags: gwt, maven, module, client, serializable

i have two maven projects, project A contents some serializable model objects and project B is the GWT project. Now i want to use some Objects from project A for RPC calls between the client and the server in project B.

so here is what i have done yet:

GWT project B xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='Index'>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.projectA.Models' />

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
<entry-point class='com.projectB.client.Index' />

<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

</module>
```

Java Object project A xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
<source path="./" />
</module>
```

I still get "No source code is available for type com.projectA.Object; did you forget to inherit a required module?" message =(

(POM dependency is set!)

Comment: Can you show you POMs? Did you add a dependency on projectA with classifier=source too? How are you "running GWT" (the compiler? the DevMode? using the gwt-maven-plugin? from your IDE? which IDE? Eclipse? with the Google Plugin for Eclipse?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i figured out i need to add this to the maven gwt plugin configuration in the POM of project B:

```
<configuration>
   <compileSourcesArtifacts>
        <compileSourcesArtifact>com.projectA:Models</compileSourcesArtifact>
   </compileSourcesArtifacts>
</configuration>
```

this tells the Maven GWT plugin to copy the sources to the web directory... Additionally you need an GWT xml file in the project B package with the following:

```
<module>
   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
   <source path='' />
</module>
```

That tells the GWT compiler to include the source of that module..

DONE

Comment: Important note: That *.gwt.xml file should be placed in right package (same as <groupId> specified in <compileSourcesArtifact>) and should have proper name (same as <artifactId> specified in <compileSourcesArtifact>).
For more details - [Using general purpose JARs as GWT library](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I thought the only solution was to use multi project setup, but that didn't seem right.  This makes much more sense.

Comment: I believe the use of "compileSourcesArtifact" is useful only when you don't have control of the artifacts you are specifying there. In this case I believe you own both modules so it is easier to turn them into "real" GWT jars.

Comment: Should i use the source jar, I don't have the source jar. but i have tried all the mentioned steps and still getting the same error. I just don't want to narrow my options

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear-
projectA structure: com.projectA.ProjectA.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="first-project">
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
<source path="./" />
</module>
```

Then projectB structure will be: com.projectB.ProjectB.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='Index'>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.projectA.first-project' />

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
<entry-point class='com.projectB.client.Index' />

<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

</module>
```

I add rename to projectA gwt.xml. Please review code. This sample should work. If your pom has correct dependency.

Comment: the naming is not the problem! i figured out i need to add this to the maven gwt plugin config in the POM of projectB:
                 <configuration>
                    <compileSourcesArtifacts>
<compileSourcesArtifact>com.projectA:Models</compileSourcesArtifact>
                    </compileSourcesArtifacts>
                </configuration>
this tells the GWT compiler to include the source of those maven packages. Now i need the right Models.gwt.xml configuration to specify the right files...